# How to return to previous part of the program (Python)

Tags: python, return

I'm novice in python and got a problem in which I would appreciate some help.
The problem in short:

1. ask for a string
2. check if all letter in a predefined list
3. if any letter is not in the list then ask for a new string, otherwise go to next step
4. ask for a second string
5. check again whether the second string's letters in the list
6. if any letter is not in the list then start over with asking for a new **FIRST** string

basicly my main question is how to go back to a previous part of my program, and it would also help if someone would write me the base of this code.
It start like this:

```
list1=[a,b,c,d]
string1=raw_input("first:")
for i in string1:
    if i not in list1:
```

Thanks

Comment: BTW: It should be `list1=['a','b','c','d']` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming

And continue to next chapter: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options, you could use iteration, or recursion. For this kind of problem I would go with iteration. If you don't know what iteration and recursion are, and how they work in Python then you should use the links Kugel suggested.

Comment: N.B. This was my first time answering a question on SO, so if anyone has any comments on my answer, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a while loop
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

pseudo code is

```
list=[a,b,c,d]
declare boolean passes = false

while (!passes)
    passes = true
    String1 = raw_input("first:")
    foreach char in string1
       if !list.contains(char)
            passes = false
            break

    if passes
        String2 = raw_input("second:")
        foreach char in string2
           if !list.contains(char)
                passes = false
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good place to start is by looking for common sequences of action and putting them in a separate subroutine.

```
# ignore this bit - it's here for compatibility
try:
    inp = raw_input  # Python 2.x
except NameError:
    inp = input      # Python 3.x

# this wraps the 'ask for a string, check if all characters are valid' bit in a single call
def GetValidString(msg, validChars):
    i = inp(msg)
    if all(ch in validChars for ch in i):
        return i
    else:
        return None

def main():
    while True:
        str1 = GetValidInput('first: ', 'aeiou'):
        if str1:
            str2 = GetValidInput('second: ', 'rstvy'):
            if str2:
                break  # good! we can leave the loop now

    # got valid values for str1 and str2
```

the logic looks like 'loop until you get string1 and it is good and you get string2 and it is also good'.

Hope that helps.